# Setup Keycloak, Oauth-proxy and Jupyterhub

Tags: oauth, keycloak, jupyterhub

I have deployed  **Jupyterhub and Keycloak** instances with Helm charts. I'm trying to authenticate user with Open Id Connect identity provider from Keycloak. But I'm pretty confused about the settings. I have followed instructions from [here](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/administrator/authentication.html#keycloak) saying I should use a GenericOAuthenticator when implementing Keycloak.

To configure OpenId Connect Client I followed [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_oidc_clients).

I also create a group membership and audience and added to the mappers of the Jupyterhub "jhub" client. As well as a group like [this](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-your-kubernetes-web-applications-with-keycloak) and created two test users and added one of them to that group.

My problem is: When I try to logging I get a `403 error Forbidden` and a URL similar to this:

```
https://jhub.compana.com/hub/oauth_callback?state=eyJzdGF0ZV9pZCI6ICJmYzE4NzA0ZmVmZTk0MGExOGU3ZWMysdfsdfsghfgh9LHKGJHDViLyJ9&session_state=ffg334-444f-b510-1f15d1444790&code=d8e977770a-1asdfasdf664-a790-asdfasdf.a6aac533-c75d-d555f-b510-asdasd.aaaaasdf73353-ce76-4aa9-894e-123asdafs
```

My questions are:

1. Am I right about using Oauth Proxy? Do I need it if I'm using Keycloak. According to Jupyterhub docs, there are two authentication flows, so I'm using Oauth-proxy as external authenticator but I'm not positive about the way I'm doing that.

> JupyterHub is often deployed with oauthenticator, where an external
> identity provider, such as GitHub or KeyCloak, is used to authenticate
> users. When this is the case, there are two nested oauth flows: an
> internal oauth flow where JupyterHub is the provider, and and external
> oauth flow, where JupyterHub is a client.

2. Does Keycloak already has a default OIDC identity provider? The menu doesn't show any after the installation. Should I have done this for each client, since it's asking for an Authorization URL or is it redundant?
   I tried to find out this but I only offers the possibility to define my own default identity provider according to [this](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#default_identity_provider) .
3. Is there a way to test the Oauth flow from the terminal or with Postman in a way that I can inspect the responses?

I could get an Id token with:

```
curl -k -X POST https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/token -d grant_type=password -d username=myuser -d password=mypassword -d client_id=my-client -d scope=openid -d response_type=id_token -d client_secret=myclientsecret
```

But how can try to login from the console?

---

Keycloak console screenshots:

[identity provider list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqPvV.png)

Relevant files:

- Jupyterhub-values.yaml:

```
hub:
  config:
    Authenticator:
      enable_auth_state: true

    JupyterHub:
      authenticator_class: generic-oauth

    GenericOAuthenticator:
      client_id: jhubclient
      client_secret: abcsecret

      oauth_callback_url: https://jhub.company.com/hub/oauth_callback
      authorize_url: https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/auth
      token_url: https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/token
      userdata_url: https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
      login_service: keycloak
      username_key: preferred_username
      userdata_params:
        state: state
  
  extraEnv:
    OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL: https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/auth
    OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL: https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/token
    OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL: https://keycloak.company.com/hub/company

ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization"
  hosts:
    - jhub.company.com
```

- keycloak-values.yaml:

```
mostly default values but added for https:

extraEnvVars: 
- name: KEYCLOAK_PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
  value: "true"

- name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
  value: "true"

- name: KEYCLOAK_ENABLE_TLS
  value: "true"

- name: KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL
  value: "https://keycloak.company.com/auth"

  ingress:
    enabled: true
    servicePort: https
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-cluster-issuer
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.org/redirect-to-https: "true"
    
    nginx.org/server-snippets: |
      location /auth {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make work with this configuration:

```
hub:
  config:
    Authenticator:
      enable_auth_state: true

      admin_users:
        - admin

      allowed_users:
        - testuser1    


    GenericOAuthenticator:
      client_id: jhub
      client_secret: nrjNivxuJk2YokEpHB2bQ3o97Y03ziA0
      oauth_callback_url: https://jupyter.company.com/hub/oauth_callback
      authorize_url: https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/auth
      token_url: https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/token
      userdata_url: https://keycloak.company.com/auth/realms/company/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
      login_service: keycloak
      username_key: preferred_username
      userdata_params:
        state: state
    JupyterHub:
      authenticator_class: generic-oauth
```

Creating the ingress myself like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jhub-ingress
  namespace: jhub
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization"

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx

  tls:
  - hosts:
    - jupyter.company.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-cert-tls-jhub

  rules:
  - host: jupyter.company.com
    http:
      paths:

      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: proxy-http
            port:
              number: 8000
```

I also removed the Oauth-prox deployment since this appears to already be done with Keycloak and it's actually redundant.

Then creating a regular user and admin roles and groups in Keycloak.
It appears the users hadn't the proper permissions in Keycloak.